getting errors with django templates
I am practicing Django lately and i get this error, can someone assist
Invalid block tag on line 17: 'else', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

The template
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% if not
request.user.is_authenticated %}
<div>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} {% if error %}
    <span style="color: red">{{ error }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% else %}
<div>
  <span style="color: red">
    Already logged in. Would you like to <a href="/logout">logout?</a>
  </span>
</div>
{% endif %} {% endblock %}


Everything corrrectly set

I'd avoid the line-break after {% if not on line 1, for reasons of readability. Also start it on a line after the end of the block declaration, for the same reason.  The error suggests that this if is not being recognized, but apart from the unconventional layout I can't see anything actually wrong. Some non-printing character accidentally in there?

@nigel222 not only for reasons of readability but also because Django's parser can't handle template tags being split over lines like that (It expects the complete template tag to be on one line).

using {% if not
user.is_authenticated %}  instead of request.user.is_authenticated solved the problem.
